# Exim: refused connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] (tcp wrappers)

Tags: centos, email, exim

I did a reboot for my system and exim stopped working. I'm not sure what went wrong...

tail /var/log/exim/main.log

```
2013-10-13 03:52:01 refused connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] (tcp wrappers)
2013-10-13 03:52:01 refused connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] (tcp wrappers)
2013-10-13 03:52:22 refused connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] (tcp wrappers)
2013-10-13 03:52:22 refused connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] (tcp wrappers)
2013-10-13 03:52:23 refused connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] (tcp wrappers)
2013-10-13 03:52:23 refused connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] (tcp wrappers)
2013-10-13 03:53:01 refused connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] (tcp wrappers)
2013-10-13 03:53:01 refused connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] (tcp wrappers)
2013-10-13 03:53:02 refused connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] (tcp wrappers)
2013-10-13 03:53:23 refused connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] (tcp wrappers)
```

cat /etc/hosts.allow

```
sshd:ALL
sendmail:ALL
mail:ALL
```

etc/init.d/exim status

```
exim (pid  35763) is running...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 8 of http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-building_and_installing_exim.html

Basically, change the "sendmail" to "exim".